# How to open an already created user in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I've created couple of users to work on different sessions using Add New User under Chrome → Settings. And, then I closed all the browsers.

Now, if I want to open a browser on some specified user, how do I do it? Whenever I try to open chrome, it always opens with a default user.

Comment: Finally, I think I found it trying with a lot of clicks here and there :-) You just need to click on the user image at top left corner and then the list of users created will be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch between existing users, click on the icon on the top left and then select the other user

[image]

---

Once Chrome is closed & relaunched, it should reopen with the same profile that was active as you last closed it.